# New Code Sign Certs (HSM) and Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, code-signing-certificate

After the final decision (Starting on June 1, 2023), the private key of code sign certificates is now uploaded to the hardware. Therefore a pfx cannot be created. In this case, what should be used in the Sign the Assembly section in visual studio?

I created and used a snk with a sn.exe, but it gives a virus warning on the client side during installation (even though I signed all dll and exe files, setup files etc. with the code sign certificate). Will using the snk file I created in the assembly sign section cause a virus warning? If so, what will we sign the codes with if we cannot create pfx with new code sign certificates?